# Huawei Account kit not working. What could be the possible solution?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-account

Using Login via account kit is not working.

Clicking Login via Huawei ID starts HMS Core update but does not finish. Hence the user cant use the login function via huawei ID.

Account kit library already upgraded to latest version but still not working.

Additionaly all kits are not working properly. Like In-app purchase kit, where it does not start at all.

Test device is Huawei Nova 5T.

Huawei ID version 6.3.308

Comment: Could you please provide more error info for us to check?

Answer (score 1):

Hello Developer,

Make ensure that you have properly configured following details in project.

- Have you included right version of Account Kit and other Kit in build.gradle file
- Check network permission is included in Manifest.xml or not.
- agconnect.json file from AppGallery should include in your project.
- check your account kit is enabled or not while registering your application in AppGalleryConnect.

Plz restart your device multiples to resolve HMS Code upgradation, sometimes it happens due to poor network.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Open AppGallery to search "hms core", then click UPDATE button to upgrade your hms core version to the latest version.

you can also download hms core directly from huawei official website as below.

https://www.huaweicentral.com/download-the-latest-hms-core-apk-34/

After your download you can directly install it.

[image]

Then try again for account kit. if you still have issue, pls refer to below official account kit demo and try.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Examples/client-sample-code-0000001050048970

Then try again for in-app purchase kit. if you still have issue, pls refer to below official iap kit demo and try.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Examples/client-sample-code-0000001050143598

Answer (score 0):

You should verify the below points

1. Use hwid version as: implementation 'com.huawei.hms:hwid:6.3.0.301'
2. If a user has installed the latest HMS Core (APK) on their phone running Android 11, but if were still asked to update the APK - [Click here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/faq-0000001050048966#section5543111215258)
3. Verify app basic configurations done correctly,

- [Adding agconnect-service.json](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/as-integration-hms-core-sdk-0000001050436235#section205571720135612) (Download the json file of your project from AGC console and place it in app folder).
- Verify the app id consistency in you **agconnect-service.json** file & AppGallery console **Project settings** page.
- [Adding build dependencies & plugins](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/as-integration-hms-core-sdk-0000001050436235#section1339835185714)

4. If still the issue persist even you checked all the above, you can find the HMS core application in **Setting > Apps > Apps** page and clear the cache. Then you can run the application.